# Float value behaviour in Python 2.6 and Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, python-2.6

I have to convert string to tuple of float.
In Python 2.7, it gives correct conversion, but in Python it is not same case.

I want same behaviour in Python 2.6

Can anyone help me why this is not same in Python 2.6 and how to do in Python 2.6.

**Python 2.6**

```
>>> a
'60.000,494.100,361.600,553.494'
>>> eval(a)
(60.0, 494.10000000000002, 361.60000000000002, 553.49400000000003)
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(a)
(60.0, 494.10000000000002, 361.60000000000002, 553.49400000000003)
>>> 

>>> for i in a.split(","):
...   float(i)
... 
60.0
494.10000000000002
361.60000000000002
553.49400000000003
>>>
```

**Python 2.7**

```
>>> a
'60.000,494.100,361.600,553.494'
>>> eval(a)
(60.0, 494.1, 361.6, 553.494)
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(a)
(60.0, 494.1, 361.6, 553.494)
>>> 

>>> for i in a.split(","):
...   float(i)
... 
60.0
494.1
361.6
553.494
```

Its not look good

**[Edit 2]**

**I just print value and condition**

```
print fGalleyTopRightOddX, ">=", tLinetextBbox[2], fGalleyTopRightOddX>=tLinetextBbox[2]

361.6 >= 361.6 False
```

I calculate `tLinetextBbox` value from string and which is `361.60000000000002` and `fGalleyTopRightOddX` value is `361.6`

I am working on **Python Django** project where **apache** is server.

1. `fGalleyTopRightOddX` i.e. `361.6` is calculated in apache environment
2. `tLinetextBbox` i.e. `361.60000000000002` is calculated on cmd means I pass `fGalleyTopRightOddX` to program which run by command `line os.system`

**[Edit 3]**
Just one more information,

when I log diction in text file then i get `tLinetextBbox` vale as `361.59999999999997`

Comment: In both cases you've got the correct value, it's just that Python 2.7 [improved how floating point numbers are displayed](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.7.html#other-language-changes). (Cue the "what every computer scientist should know about floating point number" link)

Comment: @kennytm Maybe better to say that in both cases you've got the same *incorrect* value.

Comment: @kennytm and Johan: thank you, but I still get wrong answer. I updated question, can u look again?

Answer (score 4):

In order to get the same result in Python 2.6, you have to explicitly do:

```
'%.12g' % float_variable
```

Better to create a custom function to do this as:

```
def convert_to_my_float(float_value):
    return float('%.12g' % float_value)
```

---

As per [Python's Decimal Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects) Document:

> Changed in version 2.6: leading and trailing whitespace characters are
>   permitted when creating a Decimal instance from a string.
>
> Changed in version 2.7: The argument to the constructor is now
>   permitted to be a float instance.

The answer to *Why they are behaving differently?* is, because `float.__repr__()` and `float.__str__()` methods in Python 2.7 changed.

Comment: Thanx, but I still get wrong answer. I updated question, can u look again?

Comment: I think I still didn't got your issue. Why not calculate the value `tLinetextBbox ` from the  `os` command, get required value from the function I mentioned, and pass the returned value to *your command*?

Comment: your function is not working,  `>>> convert_to_my_float(361.60000000000002)
361.60000000000002
>>> convert_to_my_float(361.6)
361.60000000000002
`

I added some info to Edit3 in question . Can u look?

Comment: What is the error your are getting? Is it `TypeError: float argument required, not str`? If yes, type-cast it to `float` before passing to the function as: `float('361.60000000000002')`